# Is this valid DTD? (official html 4.01 dtd)

Tags: html, dtd

Following declaration appears in html 4.01 dtds

```
<!ELEMENT STYLE - - %StyleSheet        -- style info -->
```

(see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/dtd.html it's in both strict.dtd and loose.dtd)

Apparently, the `;` is missing after `%StyleSheet`. The reference should have been `%StyleSheet;`

But this is the official dtd of the holy html - by far the most important dtd of all dtds - so what's going on there? Is it valid entity reference like that?

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but DTDs are irrelevant.

Comment: As was your comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is valid** without the semicolon in HTML 4.01 DTDs.  Here's an extract from the W3C's [HTML 4.01 Specification - On SGML and HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.2):

> ... Instances of parameter entities in a DTD begin with "%", then the parameter entity name, and terminated by an optional ";".

In an *XHTML* DTD it *wouldn't* be valid; they follow this recommendation (because XHTML is XML): [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition) - Character and Entity References](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references):

> ... Definition: **Parameter-entity references** use percent-sign (%) and semicolon (;) as delimiters.